# What is the current state of Ubuntu's transition from init scripts to Upstart?

Tags: 12.04, init.d, upstart

What is the current state of Ubuntu's transition from [`init.d`](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts) scripts to [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)? I was curious, so I compared the contents of `/etc/init.d/` to `/etc/init/` on one of our development machines, which is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server.

```sh
# /etc/init.d/               # /etc/init/
acpid                        acpid.conf
apache2                      ---------------------------
apparmor                     ---------------------------
apport                       apport.conf
atd                          atd.conf
bind9                        ---------------------------
bootlogd                     ---------------------------
cgroup-lite                  cgroup-lite.conf
---------------------------  console.conf
console-setup                console-setup.conf
---------------------------  container-detect.conf
---------------------------  control-alt-delete.conf
cron                         cron.conf
dbus                         dbus.conf
dmesg                        dmesg.conf
dns-clean                    ---------------------------
friendly-recovery            ---------------------------
---------------------------  failsafe.conf
---------------------------  flush-early-job-log.conf
---------------------------  friendly-recovery.conf
grub-common                  ---------------------------
halt                         ---------------------------
hostname                     hostname.conf
hwclock                      hwclock.conf
hwclock-save                 hwclock-save.conf
irqbalance                   irqbalance.conf
killprocs                    ---------------------------
lxc                          lxc.conf
lxc-net                      lxc-net.conf
module-init-tools            module-init-tools.conf
---------------------------  mountall.conf
---------------------------  mountall-net.conf
---------------------------  mountall-reboot.conf
---------------------------  mountall-shell.conf
---------------------------  mounted-debugfs.conf
---------------------------  mounted-dev.conf
---------------------------  mounted-proc.conf
---------------------------  mounted-run.conf
---------------------------  mounted-tmp.conf
---------------------------  mounted-var.conf
networking                   networking.conf
network-interface            network-interface.conf
network-interface-container  network-interface-container.conf
network-interface-security   network-interface-security.conf
newrelic-sysmond             ---------------------------
ondemand                     ---------------------------
plymouth                     plymouth.conf
plymouth-log                 plymouth-log.conf
plymouth-splash              plymouth-splash.conf
plymouth-stop                plymouth-stop.conf
plymouth-upstart-bridge      plymouth-upstart-bridge.conf
postgresql                   ---------------------------
pppd-dns                     ---------------------------
procps                       procps.conf
rc                           rc.conf
rc.local                     ---------------------------
rcS                          rcS.conf
---------------------------  rc-sysinit.conf
reboot                       ---------------------------
resolvconf                   resolvconf.conf
rsync                        ---------------------------
rsyslog                      rsyslog.conf
screen-cleanup               screen-cleanup.conf
sendsigs                     ---------------------------
setvtrgb                     setvtrgb.conf
---------------------------  shutdown.conf
single                       ---------------------------
skeleton                     ---------------------------
ssh                          ssh.conf
stop-bootlogd                ---------------------------
stop-bootlogd-single         ---------------------------
sudo                         ---------------------------
---------------------------  tty1.conf
---------------------------  tty2.conf
---------------------------  tty3.conf
---------------------------  tty4.conf
---------------------------  tty5.conf
---------------------------  tty6.conf
udev                         udev.conf
udev-fallback-graphics       udev-fallback-graphics.conf
udev-finish                  udev-finish.conf
udevmonitor                  udevmonitor.conf
udevtrigger                  udevtrigger.conf
ufw                          ufw.conf
umountfs                     ---------------------------
umountnfs.sh                 ---------------------------
umountroot                   ---------------------------
---------------------------  upstart-socket-bridge.conf
---------------------------  upstart-udev-bridge.conf
urandom                      ---------------------------
---------------------------  ureadahead.conf
---------------------------  ureadahead-other.conf
---------------------------  wait-for-state.conf
whoopsie                     whoopsie.conf
```

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure if I'm interpreting the division of responsibilities properly, as I didn't expect to see any overlap (of what framework handles which services). So I was quite surprised to learn that there was a significant amount of overlap in service references, in addition to being unable to discern which of the two was intended to be the primary service framework.

- Why does there seem to be a fair amount of redundancy in individual service handling between `init.d` and `upstart`? Is something else at play here that I'm missing?
- What is preventing `upstart` from completely taking over for `init.d`? Is there some functionality that certain daemons require which `upstart` does not yet have, which are preventing some services from converting? Or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many packages whose services were controlled using initscripts before they were ported to Upstart continue to ship an "initscript" in /etc/init.d/ which is actually a symbolic link to /lib/init/upstart-job which translates initscript syntax to approximately equivalent upstart syntax. On my system, for example, 51 of the 90 "initscripts" are actually symbolic links to /lib/init/upstart-job.